# Uninstall before installing a windows service

Tags: windows-services, installation

I am reading about how you can create an .exe that will install a windows service to the server.

Say I already have the windows service installed and I want to perform an update. Is there a way for the installer to uninstall (stop the service, delete it, uninstall it) the currently running service and then install the updated version?

Comment: are you wanting to do this in your application at runtime (e.g. user clicks a button to install/uninstall the service) or automatically during installation (e.g. via MSI?)

Answer (score 3):

Don't be that drastic -- if possible, just stop the service, replace the files you need to, and then (optionally) restart the service.

If you delete the service from the SCM, you lose any post-install configuration done by the user -- custom logon credentials, the settings that dictate what to do when the service crashes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to create an exe to do this, the "sc" command can uninstall, update, and install services on Windows for you. See:

- [Using SC.EXE to Develop Windows NT Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810435.aspx)
- [How to create a Windows service by using Sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192)

If you still really want to do this by creating your own executable you certainly can, if you can let us know what language you're working in code samples can be provided.